# Mathematical notation in a machine learning problem, majority rule

Tags: statistics, notation, machine-learning

(I apologise that the title may be a bit confusing and I don't know if this is the right community to ask my question.)

This is a mathematical notation problem in the field of machine learning.

A little context:

> In my machine learning problem, I want to classify an individual based on the samples I have of each individual (i.e. each person has multiple samples).
> Once I have made the prediction, I get the predicted class for each of the samples, but what I want is a global classification of the individual to one of the two classes.
> What I do is to count the number of samples that have been assigned to each class, and depending on this establishing a threshold, k, where an individual will be classified as Class 1 if the number of samples classified as Class 1 exceeds that threshold.

My problem is that I don't have much knowledge of formal mathematical writing, and I would like to translate the above into mathematical notation. I have written the following but I don't know if it is correct.

$$
Y=1, \sum_{i=0}^{n}\hat{y_{i}}\Leftrightarrow \hat{y_{i}}=1 > k\sum_{i=0}^{n}\hat{y_{i}}
$$

where $\hat{y_{i}}$, denotes each individual element of the vector with the predictions for each sample.

In summary, what I want to write is: The individual will be assigned to *class 1* if, the number of samples classified as *'1'* is greater than *k* times the total number of samples of the individual.

Comment: There are many ways to express this. If you are writing a paper, you may want to keep consistency: if you use specific notation for this, you shall use more of it throughout the paper. This might not be viable given that you posted this question. What you expressed in words is completely fine to me and there is no problem in using words.

Comment: Do you really want the number to exceed some $k$ rather than the proportion to exceed some $k$?

Comment: You could use an indicator function such as $\hat{Y} = \mathbf{1}_{\left[\sum \hat{y}_i >k\right]}$

Comment: @Snoop, Indeed, I am writing a paper and I wanted to put what I said in words in a more mathematical formal way, although I suppose it is not entirely necessary.

Comment: @Henry, maybe I have expressed it wrong, yes, I want to indicate when a *k* percentage of the total samples is exceeded. The solution you indicate seems interesting to me, but isn't it necessary to add something else? In your proposal, how do we indicate that the sum of the samples is only those whose value is '1', and another question, is it assumed that the percentage *k* applies to the total number of samples?, (not all individuals have the same number of samples).

Comment: I had assumed in my indicator function that the other class was $0$ so $\sum \hat{y}_i$ is simply the number of class $1$ predictions for that individual.  If you wanted $k$ to be a proportion, you could have something like  $\hat{Y} = \mathbf{1}_{\left[\sum \hat{y}_i >kn\right]}$.  If you wanted to say this was for individual $j$ but with proportion $k$ constant across individuals you could add a further subscript, with $\hat{Y_j} = \mathbf{1}_{\left[\sum_i \hat{y}_{i,j} >kn_j\right]}$.  Some readers might still welcome an explanation in words

Comment: @Henry I like your approach with the indicator function, I see it simple and concise. If you want to write it as an answer, I would vote it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As requested in comments:*

Assuming that the other class is $0$ so $\sum \hat{y}_i$ is simply the number of class $1$ predictions for that individual, you could use an indicator function  such as $$\hat{Y} = \mathbf{1}_{\left[\sum \hat{y}_i >k\right]}$$

If you wanted $k$ to be a proportion threshold rather a count, you could have something like $$\hat{Y} = \mathbf{1}_{\left[\sum \hat{y}_i >kn\right]}$$

If you wanted to say this was for individual $j$ but with proportion $k$ constant across individuals you could add a further subscript, with $$\hat{Y_j} = \mathbf{1}_{\left[\sum_i \hat{y}_{i,j} >kn_j\right]}$$

Some readers might still welcome an explanation in words.

Answer (score 0):

How about the function $$
\hat y=\frac{\max(0,N_1-k)}{N_1-k}
$$where $N_1≤N≠k$ denotes the number of samples classified as class 1 and $k<N$ as the threshold.

Edit:
I've modified the numerator and denominator in regards to the comment of @Henry in the case of $N_1=k$. If you want to classify the features as $1$ you can follow Henry's advice and use $\hat k=k-1/2$.

If you want to classify the features as $0$ then you use $\hat k = k +1/2$

Comment: Just curious: why did you not write $\hat y=\frac{\max(0,N_1-k)}{N_1-k}$?  In any case, your expression breaks if $N_1=k$ as you get $\frac00$. Perhaps $\hat y=\frac{\max(0,N_1-k+\frac12)}{N_1-k+\frac12}$ to avoid this if you want the number to strictly exceed $k$

Comment: @Henry I am used to that notation in  machine learning papers and books, maybe it is a convention. Btw, I've edited my answer in regards to your comment. Thank you

Comment: You can also write $\max(0,\,x)$ as $x^+$, although in this case we'd still want $x$ in brackets.

Comment: @Han, I appreciate your help, your function is correct, but it does not reflect the way I actually have the algorithm implemented. Expressed differently: $id_{n}=class1 \;\;  if \: \; count(id_{n}\_class1\_samples) > k\cdot id_{n}\_total\_samples$, where $k$, represents a percentage, usually between $0.67-0.8$, and $id_{n}$ is the identifier of a specific individual. I would like to translate this mathematically, in the form of the function I wrote in my question.